# Update existing layout block in admin Custom design tab in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout

In my layout files I have existing block with following structure:

```
<block type="mymodule/news" name="catalog.help" after="left_nav" template="catalog/navigation/help.phtml"/>
```

So now I would like to add extra info to this block in admin interface under "Custom design > Custom Layout Update" in certain Category without having to repeat all the attributes and other stuff, I would just like to add extra data to it, something like this (providing same block name):

```
<block name="catalog.help">
    <action method="setData"><key>news_category_id</key><value>123</value></action>
</block>
```

Above code even works but throws up warning in log sice "type" is mandatory while creating blocks in layout. But if I also add type="mymodule/news" to attributes it stops working - setData action then no longer sets data.

I would like to keep XML in admin as simple as possible without "template" and "after" tag since they are already defined in XML file in layout. Is this possible - to reference existing block and just add stuff to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<action method="setData" block="catalog.help"><key>news_category_id</key><value>123</value></action>`.

Comment: Yes, it does. Your issue was that you were effectively trying to create a *new* block instance with the name **catalog.help**. If you had used `<reference />` instead of `<block />` your entity-based layout update would have worked a charm.

Comment: For some reason I believed `<reference />` can be used only for Structural block, meaning the ones of type `core/text_list` (usually defined in page.xml), not for all blocks.